# how to make of slopes/terrain?

Tags: c#

How to create this type of slopes/terrain in unity 5?

I am creating a game in which I need random mountain slopes. I don't need the details inside the mountain, but only its boundaries.

I want to know what are the tools in unity available to make this slope.

I'm confused whether I have to create this type of slope by code or is there any direct feature in unity for making random mountains boundaries.
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like that procedurally. I just created a behaviour that will create a senoidal track much like your picture above:

```
// written by 'imerso' as a StackOverflow answer.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SlopeTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int heightInMeters = 5;
    public int widthInMeters = 128;
    public float ondulationFactor = 0.1f;
    public Material material;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        List<Vector3> vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        List<int> triangles = new List<int>();

        for (int p = 0; p < widthInMeters; p++)
        {
            // add two vertices, one at the horizontal position but displaced by a sine wave,
            // and other at the same horizontal position, but at bottom
            vertices.Add(new Vector3(p, Mathf.Abs(heightInMeters * Mathf.Sin(p * ondulationFactor)), 0));
            vertices.Add(new Vector3(p, 0, 0));

            if (p > 0)
            {
                // we have enough vertices created already,
                // so start creating triangles using the previous vertices indices
                int v0 = p * 2 - 2;         // first sine vertex
                int v1 = p * 2 - 1;         // first bottom vertex
                int v2 = p * 2;             // second sine vertex
                int v3 = p * 2 + 1;         // second bottom vertex

                // first triangle
                triangles.Add(v0);
                triangles.Add(v1);
                triangles.Add(v2);

                // second triangle
                triangles.Add(v2);
                triangles.Add(v1);
                triangles.Add(v3);
            }
        }

        mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();

        MeshRenderer r = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        MeshFilter f = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

        if (material != null)
        {
            r.sharedMaterial = material;
        }

        f.sharedMesh = mesh;
    }
}
```

To keep it simple for you to understand though, I made it just 2D. To use it, create an empty GameObject, then put the above script on it. It has a few parameters which you can tweak as well. Good luck.